# Copiar URL para uma coluna segundo um criterio

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando com o seguinte codigo pegar a URL de uma linha inteira e armazenar em uma coluna "J" se uma outra coluna "E" contiver algum valor, isto é, não estiver vazio. O codigo executa, porem, copia a URL ignorando se a coluna "E" esta ou não vazia. Isto é, tanto faz se essa coluna possui ou não valor, a URL é gerada, conforme figura  Onde estou errando?

```
function geraURL() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


  for (var i=2; i<50;i++) {
    if (spreadsheet.getRange('E'+i).activate()!= 0) {
        spreadsheet.getRange('J'+i).activate();
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11LnRyO150lEMkDB-R7AoDHniP4sjUt4PiuLiH4/edit#gid=11393109881&range='+i+':'+i);
        spreadsheet.getRange('J'+i).activate();
    } else {
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa checar se o valor da célula está vazio através do método [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), pois o `activate` retorna um objeto.

```js
function geraURL() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


  for (var i=2; i<50;i++) {
    if (spreadsheet.getRange('E'+i).getValue()) {
        spreadsheet.getRange('J'+i).activate();
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11LnRyO150lEMkDB-R7AoDHniP4sjUt4PiuLiH4/edit#gid=11393109881&range='+i+':'+i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.